# How to check if message was deleted?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

How I can check using telegram bot api if message of user (not bot) was deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any methods mentioned in [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#getupdates) docs for your purpose.

But as a workaround you can store message ids sent by user in a database and then try to forward them to another chat. If forward was successful then that means the message is not deleted, else, the message is deleted.

Check [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#forwardmessage)